# .login and .cshrc

Tags: unix, shell

where can I find these two files if I want to modify them?

#### EDIT:

when I use echo $0 I receive `-tcsh` but I found only `.bash_profile .bash_history .bash_logout`, but not `.login .cshrc`

Answer (score 3):

They're in your home directory. Since they start with a "." character, `ls` won't show
them by default, but `ls -a` will.

If your default shell is bash (which is typical for Linux), you may not 
have .cshrc or .login files -- those files are associated with csh.

If you're using csh or tcsh, but ~/.cshrc doesn't exist, it's possible that your
environment is coming from a system-wide file, perhaps /etc/csh.cshrc or something
similar.  If you want to customize the settings for yourself, you can just create 
~/.cshrc yourself if it's not already there, perhaps using the system-wide file
as a starting point.

Files such as .bashrc or .bash_profile serve the same purpose for bash as
.cshrc does for csh. .bash_history will contain a list of recently typed bash 
commands.  .bash_logout contains commands to be run when you log out.

Comment: @Jim Lewis: found nothing, what can I do?

Comment: +1, as a non-csh user, _I_ certainly don't have those files.....

Answer (score 1):

They should be in your home directory.  Try `ls -a ~/`.

Answer (score 1):

they should be on your home directory. just do a `cd ~`. If you need to modify the default .login and .cshrc, check the csh.login and csh.cshrc under /etc.